# django-registration, fix for a glitch

Tags: python, django

I am using django-registration version 0.8

I use the default django-registration and Django auth system without any tweak. I did notice a  small glitch, once I log in as a user, if I  go to the /accounts/login/ , I still get the login entry form, how can I change that it redirect a logged in user to the main root url `/` instead of bringing this form once again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap Django's login view and do the check for already authenticated users there:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def mylogin(request, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return login(request, **kwargs)
```

Then simply use this view instead of `django.contrib.auth.views.login` in your `urls.py`

Comment: thanks alot, at where shall I be putting this method ? models.py of my app?

Comment: it's a view, so it probably feels most at home in a views.py :)